# Chrome is streaming PDF from ASP.NET ashx handler

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome

It seems that since the newer version of Chrome, the browser is trying to get my PDF (generated by an ASP.NET handler) in chunks instead of in one time. But my handler does not support this. How can i disable this behaviour server side ?

I checked it with fiddler and I see a request with a status 200, and that following by multiple requests with status 504.

Comment: What happens if you send an `Accept-Range: none` header in your initial response? (See [here](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.5).) Also I'm confident that 504 is the wrong response for "don't support range requests" (would need deeper read of RFCs to find the right one).

Comment: Dear Richard, that solved my problem, THANKS a lot, now Chrome does 1 request. And my PDF gets rendered correctly.

Comment: So I'll make it an answer….

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tell the client that you do not support range requests by sending, in your response headers:

```
Accept-Range: none
```

(See the [RFC](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.5).)

Note:

- The client can ignore that header.
- The RFCs do say you SHOULD support ranges (this is, of course, difficult with dynamic content)